# Unity smooth camera rotation on Mouse Drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a smooth camera rotation when a mouse is pressed and dragged. I have found some js libraries doing it this way - https://playground.babylonjs.com/#14KRGG#3

I would like to achieve the same result in Unity.

So far I have done is a simple drag without a smooth release. How do I replicate it in my code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.5f;
     private float X;
     private float Y;
 
     void LateUpdate() {
         if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
              transform.Rotate(-new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed, 0));
              X = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
              Y = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
              transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(X, Y, 0);

         }
           
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`Quaternion.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is the script that implements smooth rotation towards the target mouse position:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.5f;
    private float X;
    private float Y;

    float _x, _y;
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            _x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed;
            _y += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed;

            var targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_y, _x, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a variable for lerp percentage and use it together instead of `Time.deltaTime` it will be `lerpPercentage*Time.deltaTime` if you want to have control over lerping speed. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thank you but the z axis is also changing. it does not stay 0 unfortunately. how do i fix this and it is a good idea about using lerp. can it also be used to slowly come to pointer`s last location when the mouse button is released?